# Positioning a jQuery UI dialog offset from the Center

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, position

I'd like to position my jQuery UI dialogs a bit better.  The default "center" position puts them directly in the middle of the page, but it certainly looks better to have them offset about 70% up the page as they are in Facebook.  I'm looking at the .position function but am a bit unclear what the simplest solution is.

Answer (score 12):

For jquery-ui 1.9+:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ position: { my: "center", at: "top+30%", of: window } });
```

For jquery-ui 1.8:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ position: { my: "center", at: "top", of: window, offset: "0 30%" } });
```

It's something like that but play around with offset values.

Comment: +1 Awesome, helped me out for an older system using jQ UI 1.8.x.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to use the [`position()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

```
$("#dialog").dialog("widget").position({
       my: 'left',
       at: 'right',
       of: target
});
```

Or, if you already have calculated the dimensions

```
var x = 50; //calculate the 70%, with your own logic
var y = 100;
$("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position', [x,y]);
```

Or you can specify the height during initialisation of the widget

```
$("#dialgo").dialog({
     autoOpen: false, 
     width: 400 , 
     position: [300,200] 
});
```

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do some calculations.  I was hoping there would be a simpler way to do it.

Comment: +1 I just spent the last 30 minutes looking for the `position:` **[300,200]** part of this puzzle. Thanks!